# ExecuterService stopped processing one thread out of two

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, executorservice, java.util.concurrent

1. I have a list of 40000 records that needs to be processed in a for loop. Since I have a two processor system. I have created a fixedThreadPool like this:

   `int threads = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
   ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(threads);`
2. And divided my `ArrayList` into two sublists. For each of these sublists, I have created a `Callable` that performs the same function (involves iterating over the sublist and doing some processing) and returns me a `Future` object.
3. I submitted both these `Callable` using `executorServiceObject.submit(callable)` and added the returned `Future` object into my list of `Future` objects

Here is my question:

I have written a `System.Out.printLn("Processed Item" +item.id) // consider item as the name of reference variable for current iteration`

Everything was fine for some time and i could see two threads working simutaneously. But after some time, one of the threads have stopped processing. Only one thread is running. (I know this because i can see on the console that the id's given to thread 2 are not being printed anymore).

Does anyone know how this happened? I mean why ExecutorService stopped running 2nd thread.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Adding sample code as I should have done before:

```
public List<Output> processInputs(List<Input> inputs)
        throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {

    int threads = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
    ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(threads);

    List<Future<Output>> futures = new ArrayList<Future<Output>>();
    for (final Input input : inputs) {
        Callable<Output> callable = new Callable<Output>() {
            public Output call() throws Exception {
                Output output = new Output();
                // process your input here and compute the output
                return output;
            }
        };
        futures.add(service.submit(callable));
    }

    service.shutdown();

    List<Output> outputs = new ArrayList<Output>();
    for (Future<Output> future : futures) {
        outputs.add(future.get());
    }
    return outputs;
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the relevant code from your program. Ideally, you should include a [mcve] which reproduces the problem.

Comment: That may not be actually stopped. It may be in waiting state. Check the run method of non-working thread and see which line executed last.

Comment: @pikrut I have used 'Callable' so there is no run() method. Secondly the Callable is created in a for loop (1 callable for 1 sublist). Meaning the call method implementation is same for both sublists

Comment: @Kenster: Sorry, I have added the sampleCode now. I have mentoned a comment in my code which just means that I am iterating over my sublist and doing some processing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Everything was fine for some time and i could see two threads working simultaneously. But after some time, one of the threads have stopped processing. Only one thread is running. (I know this because i can see on the console that the id's given to thread 2 are not being printed anymore).

I suspect that your processing thread has thrown an exception.  The `Future.get()` method can throw `ExecutionException` ["if the computation threw an exception"](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#get()).

```
// the following might throw an exception if the background job threw
outputs.add(future.get());
```

If there was a NPE, an IOException, etc. thrown by your "process your input" code then that exception is thrown by the `Callable` and stored in the `Future` so it can be thrown by the `get()` method but wrapped in an `ExecutionException`.  This is useful so the thread that is waiting can get and and handle (log, etc.) the exception thrown by the background thread.

Instead of just having your `processInputs(...)` method throw the exception to the caller where it might be getting lost, I'd do something like the following in your `while` loop:

```
try {
   outputs.add(future.get());
} catch (InterruptedException ie) {
   // always a good pattern if the thread that is waiting was interrupted
   Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
   return;
} catch (ExecutionException ee) {
   // somehow log the error
   logger.error("Computation failed to process", ee);
   // now continue and get the next future in the list
}
```

If you don't catch and properly handle that `ExecutionException` then the processing exception will also kill the thread that calls `processInputs(...)`.

Comment: you are absolutely right, I got an ExecutionException on get() method. I already have catched these two exceptions and I am printing the stack trace on my console. Does it make sense to reprocess the data of thread 1 and get the output? Or should I just rerun the program and see if the exception is thrown once again? I mean can I do something better than logging the error in my code for such cases?

Comment: Not sure @Aman.  It depends on what you are doing.  If you processing method might work a second time around then sure you could try again.  I think you need to understand _why_ the exception is happening and whether or not a retry makes sense.

Comment: okay, I will check. Thanks for the explanation , I am accepting your answer. I am getting this exception  
                                                  
                     :java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: <openjpa-1.2.3-SNAPSHOT-r422266:938587 nonfatal store error> org.apache.openjpa.util.StoreException: Exhausted Resultset 
 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerGet(FutureTask.java:233)
 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:94)